# 32 bit dll in Office 64 bit

Tags: dll, 64-bit, ms-office, 32-bit

I understand that I cannot load a 32 bit dll in a 64 bit process. I have a 32 bit dll (VB6 component), with no source code, that is loaded in an Excel automation macro. What are my options?

Answer (score 7):

32-bit add-ins are [not supported](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831.aspx#odc_office2010_Compatibility32bit64bit_ActiveXControlCOMAddinCompatibility) on 64-bit. [Microsoft recommends](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee681792.aspx) to use the 32-bit version of Office unless you run into the memory limitations of a 32-bit process which is only likely to happen if you need to deal with extremely large spreadsheets:

> The recommendations for which edition of Office 2010 to install are as follows:
>
> - If users in your organization depend on existing extensions to Office, such as ActiveX controls, third-party add-ins, in-house solutions built on previous versions of Office, or 32-bit versions of programs that interface directly with Office, we recommend that you install 32-bit Office 2010 (the default installation) on computers that are running both 32-bit and 64-bit supported Windows operating systems.
> - If some users in your organization are Excel expert users who work with Excel spreadsheets that are larger than 2 gigabytes (GB), they can install the 64-bit edition of Office 2010. In addition, if you have in-house solution developers, we recommend that those developers have access to the 64-bit edition of Office 2010 so that they can test and update your in-house solutions on the 64-bit edition of Office 2010.

If you need to go with the 64-bit version because of the memory limitations you have [the following options](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee691831.aspx#odc_office2010_Compatibility32bit64bit_ActiveXControlCOMAddinCompatibility):

> - If you have the source code, you can generate a 64-bit version yourself,
> - You can contact the vendor for an updated version,
> - You can search for an alternative solution.

There actually is a fourth option which is not mentioned in this article by Microsoft: You can create a 32-bit out-of-process COM server which serves as a proxy between your 64-bit macros and the legacy 32-bit COM components  or create a COM+ application. A sample is provided here:

> [Accessing 32-bit DLLs from 64-bit code](http://blog.mattmags.com/2007/06/30/accessing-32-bit-dlls-from-64-bit-code/)

Comment: There is no 64 bit compiler for VB6.

Comment: @Joshua: No there isn't. But the Microsoft article talks about general solutions to this problem.

Comment: "Accessing 32-bit DLLs from 64-bit code" has moved. I've fixed the link.

Comment: After another four years, how is this still a thing? The problem is just as acute as it was in 2013.

Comment: @Maury Markowitz I was able to migrate an add-in from VB6 to VB.NET. It remains to be seen whether this will be 64-bit-compatible.

Comment: @MauryMarkowitz It's 2020 and Covid19 is sweeping the earth.  But the true hell is getting 32 bit DLLs to work in 64 bit Office installs.